# QueryPath find elements with namespaced attributes

Tags: php, querypath

I'm not finding a way to retrieve all elements that have an attribute `ec:edit`. I've only found examples getting namespaced elements, but not attributes.

And there is also no result when searching the attributes with `attr()` or `hasAttr()`.

dbpedia example:

```
foreach ($qp->branch()->find('foaf|page') as $img) {
   print $img->attr('rdf:resource') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

rdf file sample:

```
<dbpprop:artist rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Beatles" />
```

But this won't retrieve any results:

```
$edits = $htmldocument->find('div[mc|edit];
foreach ($edits as $key => $value) {
    echo $value->attr('mc:edit');
}
```

sample data:

```
<div mc:edit="stuff"> // etc
```

I get nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, lambdas solve everything:

```
find('div')->filterLambda('return qp($item)->hasAttr("mc:edit");');
```

Comment: Can you please also help me for getting this type of elements in QueryPath? 

For example: <plugin:text content="filepath"/>

I also have asked question for this. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28707105/how-to-fetch-custom-or-namespaced-elements-in-querypath. 

I will be thankful to you If you can help me on it. 

Thanks.