# How to fetch custom or namespaced elements in QueryPath?

Tags: domdocument, querypath

I'm trying to fetch my custom elements in QueryPath library. But QueryPath does not work. Can anyone please help me how I can do it in QueryPath? See sample code below;

```
<plugin:text path="filename" />
```

Moreover, I also checked the PhpSimpleDom library in detail. Although it works good for me. But it does not provide the full support of css selectors and more. I also have face a very bad memory problem in PhpSimpleDom.

Can anyone please help me to fetch above mentioned element in QueryPath?

Thanks
Smac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://github.com/pode/reiseplanlegger/blob/master/api/dbpedia.php:

rdf:

```
<rdf:RDF><rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/John_Frandsen_(footballer)"><dbpprop:placeOfBirth rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Denmark"/><dbpedia-owl:birthPlace rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Denmark"/></rdf:Description>/rdf:RDF>
```

code:

```
// Fetch the URL and select all rdf:Description elements.
// (Note that | is the CSS 3 equiv of colons for namespacing.)
// To add the context, we pass it in as an option to QueryPath.
$qp = qp($url, 'rdf|Description', array('context' => $cxt));

[...]

// Here, we use rdf|* to select all elements in the RDF namespace.
$qp->top()->find('rdf|about');
```

**(Note that | is the CSS 3 equiv of colons for namespacing.)**